# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 133:

Tags: android, json, google-directory-api

I want to draw driving route between two location with two waypoints when I make the url for getdriving direction api it says

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 133 but the url gives json
```

like this  [my gerdirection api url](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=9.966654,76.316811&destination=9.948683,76.346359&waypoints=optimize:true%7C9.99709,76.316811%7C9.966654,76.316811&AIzaSyDOidVs6_dHl0cjEJ0-OhMfUY0oNFf1SOE%20http://)

So when I googled it said to use urlencoder when i use that in my url error is not thrown but my json is empty like this

```
error_message   "Invalid request. Missing the 'origin' parameter."
routes  
status  "INVALID_REQUEST"
```

plz do say me where i went wrong

my code

```
public String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {
    final LatLng source = new LatLng(dsla, dslo);
    final LatLng path1 = new LatLng(dp1la, dp2lo);
    final LatLng path2=new LatLng(dp2la,dp2lo);
    final LatLng dest = new LatLng(ddla, ddlo);
    String origin = "origin=" + source.latitude + "," + source.longitude;
    String waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true"+"|"+ path1.latitude + ","+ path1.longitude +"|"+ path2.latitude +","+ path2.longitude ;
    String destination = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
   String way="",sour="",desty="";
    try {
        way = URLEncoder.encode(waypoints, "UTF-8");
      desty = URLEncoder.encode(destination, "UTF-8");
     sour = URLEncoder.encode(origin, "UTF-8");
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    }
    String key = "AIzaSyDOidVs6_dHl0cjEJ0-OhMfUY0oNFf1SOE ";
    String params = origin+ "&" + destination+ "&" + waypoints +"&"+key;
    String output = "json";

   // String url1="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
            +output + "?" +params;
    Log.d("taqg",url);
    return url;
}
```

my parsejson

```
 public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
String results="";
// constructor


public String getJSONFromUrl(final  String url) {
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                json = sb.toString();
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }


            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        results=json;
            Log.d("tag",results);
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();

   return results;

    }
  }
```

say me if there any mistake in parsejson also

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem in your uri encoding.

For the direction uri, I used this code. Its works fine. Modify it according to your needs..

```
private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){
    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;
    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;
    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;
    // Output format
    String output = "json";
    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;
}
```